# C++ Call Lua: use setField to point itself?

Tags: c++, lua

Here is the thing, in C++:

```
l_newTable(L);                  //Stack: newtable
l_getGlobal(L, "A");            //Stack: newtable A
l_setfiled(-2, "__index")       //Stack: newtable       => newtable.__index = A
```

That is normal. However if I want to set a new table's __newindex to itsself, how to write the code? It needs to set __newindex to newTable itsself, but use setfield will call Pop, that means:

```
l_newTable(L);                 //Stack: newtable
l_setfield(-1, "__newindex")   //Stack: -1              => newtable will pop out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [lua_pushvalue](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pushvalue) to duplicate `newtable` before its value gets popped from the stack:

```
lua_newTable(L);                 //Stack: newtable
lua_pushvalue(L, -1);            //Stack: newtable, newtable
lua_setfield(-2, "__newindex")   //Stack: newtable  => newtable.__newindex = newtable
```

Comment: Got it, another question is if I set userdata.__newindex = table, is that means I can add values into userdata?